# Encog load CSV file with customized network

Tags: csv, encog

I want to load data from CSV file like this:

```
var format = new CSVFormat('.', ' '); 
IVersatileDataSource source = new CSVDataSource(filename, false, format);
var data = new VersatileMLDataSet(source); ...
```

Then I have two options:

**Use EncogModel**

```
var model = new EncogModel(data);
model.SelectMethod(data, MLMethodFactory.TypeFeedforward); ...
```

**Make own network**

```
var network = new BasicNetwork();
network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(null, true, 11));
network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(), true, 8));
network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationTANH(), true, 5)); 
...
IMLDataSet trainingSet = new BasicMLDataSet(input, output);
```

---

I don't know how to set number of layers, neurons and activation functions with first option (Encog Model). All I get is some default feedforward network with one hidden layer only.

---

I don't know how can get easily input and output arrays separately for my own network (second option) from VersatileMLDataSet. I can get whole array (input + output), but there must be a way how to get only input array or output array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found answer in documentation (*Encog Method & Training Factories, page 75*), with EncogModel is possible customize network like this:

```
var methodFactory = new MLMethodFactory();
var method = methodFactory . Create(
MLMethodFactory .TYPEFEEDFORWARD,
”?:B−>SIGMOID−>4:B−>SIGMOID−>?”,
2,
1);
```

> The above code creates a neural network with two input neurons and one
>   output neuron. There are four hidden neurons. Bias neurons are placed
>   on the input and hidden layers. As is typical for neural networks,
>   there are no bias neurons on the output layer. The sigmoid activation
>   function is used between both the input and hidden neuron, as well
>   between the hidden and output layer. You may notice the two question
>   marks in the neural network architecture string. These will be filled
>   in by the input and output layer sizes specified in the create method
>   and are optional. You can hard-code the input and output sizes. In
>   this case the numbers specified in the create call will be ignored.