# Encog uses customized model for feedforward neural network

Tags: encog

I am trying to set a number of layers, neurons and activation functions to my Encog Model. [Following this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39521796/encog-load-csv-file-with-customized-network), I tried to implement the MLMethodFactory.

```
EncogModel model = new EncogModel(data);

MLMethodFactory  methodFactory = new MLMethodFactory();
MLMethod method = methodFactory.create(MLMethodFactory.TYPE_FEEDFORWARD, "?:B->SIGMOID->6:B->SIGMOID->5:B->SIGMOID->?" ,5,1);

model.selectMethod(data, method.toString());
```

The above code however returns me this error message:

org.encog.EncogError: Don't know how to autoconfig method: [BasicNetwork: Layers=4]
    at org.encog.ml.model.EncogModel.selectMethod(EncogModel.java:379)
    at application

How can I solve this issue?